# Error: “Picklist value in picklist not found” Opportunity Stage - Sales Process

Tags: api, deployment, picklist, metadata

I have different Record Types on my opportunity and different Sales Prosses associated with them to be able select different values in picklist field Stage depending on Record Types. I add custom values in picklist field Stage and select them in one Sales Process. But when I am trying to deploy next error occur

> Error: Picklist value: not found.

```
<businessProcesses>
    <fullName>Custom Sales Process</fullName>
    <description>Sales Process for ...</description>
    <isActive>true</isActive>
    <values>
        <fullName>01 New</fullName>
        <default>false</default>
    </values>
    <values>
        <fullName>02 Prospecting</fullName>
        <default>false</default>
    </values>
    <values>
        <fullName>03 Qualifying</fullName>
        <default>false</default>
    </values>
    <values>
        <fullName>custom value 1</fullName>
        <default>false</default>
    </values>
</businessProcesses>
```

API version in package.xml is 39

Please, help me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you need to include [`StandardValueSet`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_standardvalueset.htm) to your `package.xml`.

to deploy custom values to `Opportunity.StageName` field use next lines:

```
<types>
    <members>OpportunityStage</members>
    <name>StandardValueSet</name>
</types>
```